# What is a functioning power turret?

Tags: target-for-today

One of the modifiers for table 5-6 Bomber Defensive Fire Resolution is:

> +1 for defensive fire by a functioning power turret (electrical power, hydraulic)

But I'm unsure as to what a "functioning power turret" is? Is that just another term for any of the twin guns(undamaged) on the B-17?, or just the Ball Turret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [errata](http://www.stevenkdixon.com/v1_3_TFT%20_Rules.pdf) posted last year clarifies the definition of a power turret in rule 5.5.2.

> Powered Turrets: Chin (B-17G), Nose (B-24J), Top
> Turret and Ball Turret (All models of B17 and B24) and tail guns (B-24). The Tail Guns (B17) are
> not powered.